# Can I destroy a drone that is overflying on my backyard?

Tags: real-estate, drones

The other day, a friend of mine told me that a drone was overflying on his backyard and he hit it throwing up a rock to it.

That incident bring me a few questions. Is that legal? The air in my backyard is included as my property? Using an exaggerated example: if an helicopter is overflying my backyard, am I allowed to bring it down because it is invading  my property?

Comment: If your jurisdiction is not the US, then please state it and add an appropriate tag.

Comment: Downvoted for not finding the dupe and not stating country/jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that legal?

**No**, it is the crime of "[Willful Damage](https://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/offences/wilful-damage)" in Australian jurisdictions.

> The air in my backyard is included as my property?

**No**, neither are any minerals that might be under it.

> Using an exaggerated example: if an helicopter is overflying my backyard, am I allowed to bring it down because it is invading my property?

**No**, in addition to willful damage this would be [Reckless Endangerment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endangerment), [Aggravated Assault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault) and [Attempted Murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempted_murder).

Comment: Unless the drone fires first...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FI--wFfipvA